# SharePoint Online Storage

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, storage

How much storage is per default for SharePoint Online and Office 365?

A client of mine would like to know how much storage he will get. I cant find an updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is based off the number of E1-4 users you license. The current figures, I believe, are 10GB plus 500MB per licensed E1-4 user.  The more users you license, the more storage you get. This is supposed to be increasing to 500GB plus 500MB per licensed user the last I saw on the roadmap.

You can buy additional storage on a per month basis if you need more storage that what your licensing will give you. You have flexibility when creating site collections on how to divvy up that allocation, you can set your own quotas.

Users will get 1TB of OneDrive space, which is soon going to be unlimited.

Answer (score 3):

It depends your plan as far as I know.

[SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business: software boundaries and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for-Business-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)

Now can customize [storage quota](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-collection-storage-limits-77389c2c-8e7e-4b16-ab97-1c7103784b08) for each site collection

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally it depends on the number of users . They have licensing rules for data space per user.